# asynchronous function calls in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous

Suppose you have three classes A,B,C each having its own search function. I want to run a key ( say 'searchKey' ) concurrently using all the three search functions. How do I stop the other two search functions if I get the result from one of the three functions ?

Also would this run faster than the case where I have a distinct hashmap in each class and search them one after the other since the search resolves to a constant time complexity ?

Comment: Check this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

Comment: Thanks , this was really helpful

Comment: You can just use a good ol' concurrent queue but only read one element (the first you get). The other threads will put their results into that queue later but nobody will use them. Create one queue, call searchKey (which takes a key and a queue) on all objects. wait for the first input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to expose a public method to stop the search e.g. a flag to cancel the Threads in their respective class.

To your second point, the time complexity for a key search in a `HashMap` is usually `O(1)` (worst case `O(n)` if those keys are in the same hash bucket). So there is not much room for optimization since it's already blazing fast. You would not even notice that if you are searching the `HashMaps` in sequence.

Comment: Thank you, I was thinking of something similar but then just thought for a second that if there's any clean inbuilt provision for achieving the same, its good to know.